# Find the height and width of rectangle object in image using python?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

[image: grid image]

Any one have idea to find the height and width of rectangle object in grid image.
The grid has 11.5 mm length one to another center point of circle.
if any possible way share the link of website or code in python(opencv).

Comment: first, "calibrate" the camera. you need "intrinsics", which is a focal length (in pixels), the principal point (cx, cy), and distortion coefficients -- then pick a method to get a mask/contour/bounding-box for your object

Comment: we already done this method but we need more accuracy. so we rise a question how to increase accuracy in measurement. For that one person reply to use ruler or grid to measure the object. we don't know what is ruler. we have fanuc grid. but we don't know how to use this grid to get proper measurement. if any possible way share the link.

Comment: please review [ask] and [mre] and https://idownvotedbecau.se/. your question should contain all relevant information. you are not gonna get spoonfeeding here. look for formal education. -- are you in any way affiliated with that "measuring drill bits" team? your comment suggests that.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73245761/how-to-improve-the-cnn-learning-in-same-object-but-different-length-and-breath-a